# Okta as IDP for Azure

Tags: azure, saml, okta, idp

So I want to provide access to users over Okta to Azure.
We have local AD which is not synced to MS Azure account
We have custom domain inside Azure AD

There is also 2nd part of this where we want to sync local AD mail field to Workday and add some O365 users to the same tenant which is another (native) Okta app.

So looking at docs, it seems I need to install ADConnect client which will import all users to the same O365/Azure tenant. Then on the Okta, there is native o365 app that I simply need to configure (it didn't look like problematic). But for the Azure part, the documentation is not really good and I am confused what should I do with Azure.

It seems I need to add Custom SAML 2.0 Application on Okta for Azure and configure External Identities-->New SAML connection on Azure. There also should be a way how to link Okta users to AzureAD ones but they have different domains. Did I get this correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.okta.com/partners/microsoft/azure-active-directory/

Comment: Not helpful at all, nothing on that link related to may case.

Comment: Your best bet is going to be to talk to Okta or Azure support to figure it out.

Comment: k, I'll try that then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Use AAD Connect to sync on-premise users to Azure AD
2. Integrate on-premise AD with Okta
3. Use Okta's native Office 365 application to integrate Okta with Azure AD for Single Sign On. When you use this application, you don't have to do anything on Azure AD. Okta will take care of everything for you. All you need to do is follow these steps: https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Office365-Deployment/configure-sso.htm